# Drupal 7 : Can't view the newly loaded theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-themes

I've been trying to install a new theme by copying the uzipped theme folder to :

```
 1) /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/themes/
```

and later to this:

```
 2) /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal/sites/MYSITE/themes/marinelli/
```

For each installation when I go to my site's home page and select "Apprearance" I don't see my new theme in "Disabled/Enabled/Administration Theme drop down menu" [any of them]. These are the permissions of the theme directory

```
 drwxr-xr-x@ 17 MYNAME  admin  578 Feb 17 13:27 marinelli
```

I've cross checked that the version of theme I downloaded does support Drupal7. Please help me out. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: is it a drupal.org theme or your own one ? Does the theme has its theme_name.info file ?

Answer (score 0):

Files that you have put in

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal/sites/MYSITE/themes/marinelli/
```

would be recognized only if you access them by typing `http://MYSITE` in the browser.

For a local installation you should unzip [marinelli](http://drupal.org/project/marinelli) theme in

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/themes/
```

The permissions should be usually 755 for folders and 644 for files. Though i never had had to set the permission for any theme/folder files manually myself.

Assuming you are can access the site by visiting **`http://localhost/drupal`** or **`http://127.0.0.1/drupal`** in your machine.

After copying the folder to sites/all/themes, clear your cache by visiting,

**`http://localhost/drupal/admin/config/development/performance`** and clicking on **Clear all cache** button.

These steps should make Marinelli available to you in **`http://localhost/drupal/admin/appearance`**

Comment: Put the site into maintenance mode ( .../admin/config/development/maintenance) before you clear the cache.  Otherwise Drupal (D7 at least) will not check the file system for new themes.